# How to call various strings without using %s?

Tags: python

```
text1="Python"
text2="with me"
print("Study %(language)s" %{'language':text1})
```

1. This works. But I am wondering whether it is using dictionary to call string?

`print("Study %(language)s %(with whom)" %({'language':text1},{'with whom':text2}))`

2. But it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

The error says 'format requires a mapping'

Answer (score 2):

It would have worked, if you noticed that:

1. you've forgotten to put an `s` after `%(with whom)` --> `%(with whom)s`,
2. and instead of this `%({'language':text1},{'with whom':text2})` --> `%{'language':text1,'with whom':text2}`

so the line would be like this:

```
print("Study %(language)s %(with whom)s" %{'language':text1,'with whom':text2})
```